# float multiple elements side by side in html

Tags: html, css, css-float

let's say I have four `<p>` and all `<p>` elements are floated to left, but the second `<p>`'s height is longer than others as the picture below:
[image]

What I don't understand is, why p4 is not under p1? why it is under p3? You might say as the p2 is in the way because of its height, but why p4 has to be moved from current position to the position under p1, can't p4 just be placed under p1 directly and there is nothing to do with the height of p2?

Comment: Send code, so we will check where is error

Comment: You can use display: inline-block;

Comment: "What I don't understand is, why p4 is not under p1?". Neither do we, but without knowing your code, or knowing the size of viewport you had at the time, we can't help you. That's just an abstract screenshot. It's a useful illustration but is otherwise meaningless in terms of determining the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A floated element is shifted to the left (or right) until it touches the edge of its containing box or another floated element.

And since the 2nd is in its *way* it stops there.

*Sample 1 - Float*

[image]

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 50px;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

---

*Sample 2 - Float*

[image]

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

---

*Sample 3 - Float*

[image]

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

---

*Updated based on a comment*

For a comparison, here is how inline blocks behave in a similar setup.

*Sample - Inline blocks*

[image]

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why 4 starts at 4's position first? why it is not under 1 position first, then it doesn't matter 2 is in the way?

Comment: @slowjams The 4th is after 3rd, though since there is no place left for it to fit in one line it _slides_ under the 3rd (the _red_ line). Now, in last sample there is no element that spans below that _red_ line, hence it _floats_ all the way to the left, but in sample 1 and 2, one of its siblings spans across that _red_ line and blocks its way to float all the way to the left. The _red_ line is defined by the element closest to the 4th, in this case the 3rd. In comparison with for example inline blocks, where it is the highest element that defined where the _red_ line is vertically positioned.

Comment: @slowjams I also added a 4th sample, showing how inline blocks behave in a similar setup

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `float: left;` you are obligating p4 to use vertical space to keep it's priority to stay right of the left objects (Which is in fact the most left for an object to be at that vertical line).

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code instead of float

```
div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use This Code

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

ul li {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <ul>

    <li><p>Content 1</p></li>

    <li><p>Content 2</p></li>

    <li><p>Content 3</p></li>

    <li><p>Content 4</p></li>

  </ul>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: PSss!!  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16497456) Please explain the changes you have done to me. This was under a review edit audit.